# rm -r in shell script (my first *.sh)

Tags: bash, shell, rm, delete-file

I would like to delete some folder on an Ubuntu 8.04 Server.

I would like to start a script to delete this folder.

I start an ssh session to the server.

My script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -r /var/lib/backuppc/pc/PC1/
rm -r /var/lib/backuppc/pc/PC2/
```

I run the script like this:

```
sh scriptname.sh
```

But I get this message:

```
rm: cannot remove `/var/lib/backuppc/pc/PC1/\r': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove `/var/lib/backuppc/pc/PC1/\r': No such file or directory
```

I'm sorry but I don't use ever a shell script on linux.
I think it my fault because I don't know the basics :-(

Can somebody help me? I've to delete ~80 folder... :-(

Comment: Did you create your script on Windows? It has a carriage return (`\r`) and line feed (`\n`) at the end of each line. Unix/Linux only wants a line feed, `\n`. On the server, try, `dos2unix scriptname.sh`.

Comment: Without wanting to sound condescending, can I suggest that if this is your first script, please be _very_ careful about using `rm -r` and (if on a Unix platform) _never_ run it as root. I say this from bitter personal experience.

Comment: Yes, I created it on Windows with Notepad++.

Comment: Ubuntu 8 is 7 years old!

Comment: My granddad liked Ubuntu 8 so much. `:-)` If he weren't dead, he would ask you to move on to 14!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like there is some "junk" characters after your folder name (namely, `\r`). To be sure, type `cat -A scriptname.sh` and check if you can see some weird characters in the end of the lines. If so, I think the easiest thing for you (since you have few lines) is to manually delete the ending of those lines and re-type again. (I'm talking about the last two or three characters only)
Type `cat -A scriptname.sh` and see if the characters disappeared. If so, you should be good to go with your code.

Comment: Thank you very much! 
There were some characters.


Thats my way to create shell under windows and run it on unix:

1.Creating a script with notepad++
2.Select View - Show Symbol - Show All Characters (I see CR&LF)
3.Select Edit - EOL Conversion - UNIX Format (CR&LF changed to LF)

Comment: So I'm guessing that solved your problem? May I suggest that you start writing your bash code in Linux? For a "in-command-line" editor you can use `nano` (easier) or `vim` (maybe a little too advanced). For a "graphical-user-interface" editor you can use `gedit` or `geany` (both color code your script, so it is a lot easier to visualize).

Comment: Thank you TomCho! - yes my problem is solved. - I'll take a look at your suggested editors.

Comment: Hey, I'm not saying because I want extra points or anything, but when an answer solves your problem you should click the "check mark" right besides the answer. That way you indicate the community that you solved your issue with that, you earn points, other people earn points and everybody can quickly see which of the answers worked for you. This way the whole community benefits. You can read more about it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) ;)